# Can python re placeholders be used inside functions? If yes, how? [or more generally - one-liner to urlescape a string]

Tags: python, python-re

Is it possible to use \1 matchholders in python sub functions? e.g. ord("\1")  I notice this is not working:

```
$ python3.7 -c 'import re; a="fred<was>=he re, n=-3.13e-05;\n"; print(re.sub(r"([^'0'-'9''A'-'Z''a'-'z'\.\-\_])","%"+hex(ord("\\1")), a)) ' 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 2 found
```

And the "length 2" is very unexpected, because as you can see, it is not 2:-

```
$ python3.7 -c 'import re; a="fred<was>=he re, n=-3.13e-05;\n"; print(re.sub(r"([^'0'-'9''A'-'Z''a'-'z'\.\-\_])","(\\1)", a)) '             
fred(<)was(>)(=)he( )re(,)( )n(=)-3.13e-05(;)(
)
```

Investigating what it is in there shows that functions are receiving the literal '\1' instead of the substitution (0x5C is "\" and 0x31 is "1"):

```
$ python3.7 -c 'import re; a="fred<was>=he re, n=-3.13e-05;\n"; print(re.sub(r"([^'0'-'9''A'-'Z''a'-'z'\.\-\_])","%"+hex(ord("\\1"[0])), a)) ' 
fred%0x5cwas%0x5c%0x5che%0x5cre%0x5c%0x5cn%0x5c-3.13e-05%0x5c%0x5c
$ python3.7 -c 'import re; a="fred<was>=he re, n=-3.13e-05;\n"; print(re.sub(r"([^'0'-'9''A'-'Z''a'-'z'\.\-\_])","%"+hex(ord("\\1"[1])), a)) ' 
fred%0x31was%0x31%0x31he%0x31re%0x31%0x31n%0x31-3.13e-05%0x31%0x31
```

hence my question... is there a trick or alternative I can use to get the actual placeholder into ord() ?

...

Alternatively: I'm in an environment where I can't rely on urllib being available.

Bottom line - I'm trying to reproduce something like this:-

```
$ perl -e '$a="fred<was>=he re, n=-3.13e+05;\n"; $a=~s/([^A-Za-z0-9\._-])/sprintf("%%%02X", ord($1))/seg; print "$a\n"' 
fred%3Cwas%3E%3Dhe%20re%2C%20n%3D-3.13e%2B05%3B%0A
```

Pardon, by the way, for asking - a couple of hours in google has not yielded an answer yet, I'm new to python, and search terms like "\1" are tricky...

Comment: *Alternatively: I'm in an environment where I can't rely on urllib being available.* - since it's part of Python's standard library - how would that be?

Comment: @JonClements - thanks Jon - I'm new, so don't know these things.  I'm coding an add-on and comments from other authors tell us not to rely on existence of things you "import" because it frequently breaks your product on end-user machines.

Irrespective of that, I am interested to know if there's an answer to my actual question still.  I've found similar questions/answers on stackoverflow, and nobody answers the actual question - they just provide alternatives, so I'm still wondering!

Comment: python3.7 -c 'import urllib.parse; a="fred<was>=he re, n=-3.13e+05;\r\nX\xff\00"; a=urllib.parse.quote(a, safe=""); print(a) '

Answer (score 0):

Update: I do still want to know the answer to my original question, but in the meantime.

a) @JonClements pointed out that urllib is always available (yay! thanks Jon).

b) I constructed this ugly, but working, solution:-

```
import re
a="fred<was>=he re, n=-3.13e+05;\r\nX\xff\00"
b=''
while True:
    m = re.search(r"(.*?)([^0-9A-Za-z\.\-\_])(.*)", a, flags=re.S)
    if not m:
        break
    b=b+m.group(1);
    b=b+'%'+'%02x' % ord(m.group(2))
    a=m.group(3)

a=b+a

print(a)
```

which gives

```
fred%3cwas%3e%3dhe%20re%2c%20n%3d-3.13e%2b05%3b%0d%0aX%ff%00
```

- Warning: No idea what unicode might do

Comment: Less hacky: `re.sub('([^0-9A-Za-z._-])', lambda m: f'%{ord(m.group(1)):02x}', a)` (but I'd definitely still stick with quote/quote_plus from urllib.parse